# How to change itemsperpage in typescript using angularjs2?

Tags: typescript, angular

This is my code

```js
config.js:- 

  /**
 * PLUNKER VERSION (based on systemjs.config.js in angular.io)
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 * Override at the last minute with global.filterSystemConfig (as plunkers do)
 */
(function(global) {

  var ngVer = '@2.0.0-rc.1'; // lock in the angular package version; do not let it float to current!

  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var  map = {
    'app':                        'src', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'https://npmcdn.com/angular2-in-memory-web-api' // get latest
  };

  //packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.ts',  defaultExtension: 'ts' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

  var packageNames = [
      '@angular/common',
      '@angular/compiler',
      '@angular/core',
      '@angular/http',
      '@angular/platform-browser',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
      '@angular/router-deprecated',
      '@angular/testing',
      '@angular/upgrade',
  ];

  // add map entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/common@0.0.0-3'
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    map[pkgName] = 'https://npmcdn.com/' + pkgName + ngVer;
  });

  // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });

  var config = {
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: {
      emitDecoratorMetadata: true
    },
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }

  // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
  if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

  System.config(config);

})(this);


/*
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/

src/app.ts:-
  
  import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {PaginationControlsCmp, PaginatePipe, PaginationService} from 'ng2-pagination';
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
providers: [PaginationService],
template: `
<div class="row">
<div class="medium-8 medium-offset-2 columns">
<h2 class="subheader"></h2>
<table><tr>
<th>EmployeeId</th>
<th>EmployeeName</th>
<th>EmployeeSalary</th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }">
<td>{{ item.EmployeeId }} 
</td>
<td> {{item.EmployeeName}}</td>
<td>{{item.EmployeeSalary}}<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event" #api>

</pagination-controls>
<select [ngModel]="selectedDevice" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
<option *ngFor="#i of devices">{{i}}</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>

`,
directives: [PaginationControlsCmp],
pipes: [PaginatePipe]
})
export class App {
  devices=[5,10,15];
  onChange(newValue){
    this.selectedDevice=newValue;
 this.paginate.itemsPerPage= newValue;
  }
collection = [{"EmployeeId":"101","EmployeeName":"Ravi","EmployeeSalary":"100"},{"EmployeeId":"102","EmployeeName":"Raju","EmployeeSalary":"100"},
{"EmployeeId":"103","EmployeeName":"saw","EmployeeSalary":"100"},{"EmployeeId":"104","EmployeeName":"rao","EmployeeSalary":"100"},
{"EmployeeId":"105","EmployeeName":"Ravi","EmployeeSalary":"100"},{"EmployeeId":"106","EmployeeName":"Raju","EmployeeSalary":"100"},
{"EmployeeId":"107","EmployeeName":"saw","EmployeeSalary":"100"},{"EmployeeId":"108","EmployeeName":"rao","EmployeeSalary":"100"}
{"EmployeeId":"109","EmployeeName":"Ravi","EmployeeSalary":"100"},{"EmployeeId":"110","EmployeeName":"Raju","EmployeeSalary":"100"},
{"EmployeeId":"111","EmployeeName":"saw","EmployeeSalary":"100"},{"EmployeeId":"112","EmployeeName":"rao","EmployeeSalary":"100"},
{"EmployeeId":"113","EmployeeName":"saw","EmployeeSalary":"100"},{"EmployeeId":"114","EmployeeName":"rao","EmployeeSalary":"100"},
{"EmployeeId":"115","EmployeeName":"saw","EmployeeSalary":"100"},{"EmployeeId":"116","EmployeeName":"rao","EmployeeSalary":"100"},
{"EmployeeId":"117","EmployeeName":"saw","EmployeeSalary":"100"},{"EmployeeId":"118","EmployeeName":"rao","EmployeeSalary":"100"},
{"EmployeeId":"119","EmployeeName":"saw","EmployeeSalary":"100"},{"EmployeeId":"120","EmployeeName":"rao","EmployeeSalary":"100"},
{"EmployeeId":"121","EmployeeName":"saw","EmployeeSalary":"100"},{"EmployeeId":"122","EmployeeName":"rao","EmployeeSalary":"100"},
];
constructor() {
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
this.collection.push(`item ${i}`);
}
}
}

src/main.ts:-
  
  //main entry point
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {App} from './app';
bootstrap(App, [])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>ng2-pagination playground</title>
     <script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.27/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/typescript@1.8.10/lib/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination/master/dist/ng2-pagination-bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
    System.import('app')
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.0/foundation.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>
    loading...
  </my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is my plunker :- https://plnkr.co/edit/2OW31JMz7Qk35ACip2Ch?p=preview
In the above code i have a table with sample json data displayed. I wrote the code for pagination that works fine, next i place dropdown for change number records to display on current page . how to change the itemsperpage on table when i select the option from dropdown using typescript in angularjs2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/5TZuv7ORqIdENodzfp3C?p=preview)

changes are as below,

```
 // <tr *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }">
 <tr *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: perpageitem, currentPage: p }">
```

in your `App` class

```
 perpageitem: number = 5;
 onChange(newValue){
     this.selectedDevice=newValue;
     this.perpageitem = newValue;
  }
```